# RhinoMocks Expectation Return Anything

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

Is there any way to setup RhinoMocks expectation without caring about return value? Something like that:

```
repository.Expect(r => r.Add(1)).Return(Anything)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if you don't specify a return value the default will be returned.  So null for objects, false for bool, 0 for int, etc.

So in your case, if you are expecting one call to the method, you could write

```
repository.Expect(r => r.Add(1)).Repeat.Once();
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  Imagine what would happen if indeterminate results came back, and as a result sometimes the test passed and sometimes it didn't!

If you don't care, I think the best way of expressing that is to use

```
default(type)
```